# Will this regex always work according to requirements stated below?

Tags: java, regex

Is this regex correct to break a sentence into 3 tokens:

1. Characters Before lowercased letters inside a parentheses
2. Lowercase letters inside a parentheses including parentheses
3. Characters after lowercased parentheses letters

`System.out.println("This is (a) test".matches("^(.*)?\\([a-z]*\\)(.*)?$"));`

The string may or may not have a parentheses lower cased letter and it may appear anywhere in the sentence. If you see a flaw in a use case I haven't considered, can you provide the correction in regex ?

For the e.g. above.

```
Group1 captures This is 
Group2 captures (a)
Group3 captures  test
```

EDIT:: How do I change the regex to achieve the following ?

If the string has (foo)(bar)(baz) how do I capture group1= empty group2=(foo) and group3=empty. And find the above pattern thrice because there are 3 parentheses.

Comment: Will the string contain new line character? And your regex will match `()` - is it OK like that?

Comment: Did you abandon this question? What was the solution after all?

Answer (score 0):

Separate from examining the regex, whenever I write a regex, I write a series of unit tests to cover each case. I'd suggest you do the same. Create four tests (at least) using the regex and testing against the strings:

- (a) This is test
- This is (a) test
- This is test (a)
- This is a test

That should cover each of the cases you've described. That's much easier and faster than trying to hand analyze the regex for each case.

Comment: Test cases are great, but to be totally sure of its correctness, you need to analyze the regex. It is common to overlook boundary test cases and test case to check whether the regex over-matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that are characters inside your lower parentesis, you should use `+`, which stands by one or more times

```
[a-z]+
```

The way it is, `This is (a) (b) test` will yield

```
Group1 captures This is 
Group2 captures (a)
Group3 captures  (b) test
```

If Group2 is expected to be `(b)` you should use a greedy regexp in Group1

Suggested test cases:

- empty - really empty, can't have a bullet point empty.
- foo(bar)baz
- (foo)(bar)(baz)
- (foo)bar(baz)
- foo(bar)(baz)bing
- foo(bar)baz(bing)
- foo(bar)
- (foo)bar

Comment: For the eg (foo)(bar)(baz) how do I capture group1= empty group2=(foo) and group3=empty

Comment: And it will find the above pattern thrice because there are 3 parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Your regex has a little problem.

You say in your definition that you have 3 groups, when in fact your pattern contains 2.

Using literal parentheses doesn't count as a group, so you'd need to use something like this:

```
"^(.*)?(\\([a-z]*\\))(.*)?$"
```

Or if you don't really want the parentheses, just the letters, you can change the order:

```
"^(.*)?\\(([a-z]*)\\)(.*)?$"
```

Other than that, it seems to be OK, but have in mind that the lower case letters between parentheses are not mandatory in your pattern.

Comment: yea i added parentheses to always capture it in group2

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first and third group to contain all characters *before* and *after* the parantheses, you must make sure they exclude `(` and `)` (your `.*` will also match groups that contain parantheses, such as `(foo)(bar)` in your second example).

So I'd replace `.*` with this `[^\\(\\)]*`.

Also, if you want to match strings that contain many substrings of the second group (like in your second example), you should have `*` after the second group.

My result was this:

```
^([^\\(\\)]*)?(\\([a-z]*\\))*([^\\(\\)]*)?$
```

This will work for the first example and the second, but the second group will eventually store only the last one found - `(bz)`.

If you want to be able to capture the second group 3 times like you said for your second example, you could try using `while m.find()` instead of `if m.matches()` (`m` is a `Matcher` object); and also change your regex a little to this:

```
([^\\(\\)]*)(\\([a-z]*\\))([^\\(\\)]*)
```

This will should the second group for every possible match in your string - `(foo)`, `(bar)`, `(bz)`.

Edit:
For some reason that I can't really explain, for me it doesn't find `(foo)`, only the other two. So I wrote a piece of code that tries to apply `find()` with a parameter, explicitly starting from some position, where the last found group ended:

```
String regex = "([^\\(\\)]*)(\\([a-z]*\\))([^\\(\\)]*)";
String text = "(foo)(bar)(bz)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

for (int reg = 0; reg < text.length(); reg+=(m.end()-m.start()))
        if (m.find(reg))
            for (int group = 1; group <=m.groupCount(); group++)
                System.out.println("Group "+group+": "+m.group(group));
```

This works, and the output is:

```
Group 1: 
Group 2: (foo)
Group 3: 
Group 1: 
Group 2: (bar)
Group 3: 
Group 1: 
Group 2: (bz)
Group 3:
```

Answer (score 0):

In python:

`r=re.compile(r'([^()]*)(\([a-z)(]*\))([^()]*)')`

```
r.match('abc(xx)dd').groups()
  ('abc', '(xx)', 'dd')`
r.match('abc(xx)(dd)dd').groups()
  ('abc', '(xx)(dd)', 'dd')
r.match('(abc)').groups()
  ('', '(abc)', '')
```